Cannot install NPM in Ubuntu
I am trying to install npm on Ubuntu. First I check NPM is not installed:
jmlopez@desarrollo:/usr/share$ npm -v
Command 'npm' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install npm

Then I try to install it but I get:
jmlopez@desarrollo:/usr/share$ sudo apt install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
npm is already the newest version (8.5.1~ds-1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnode-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I tried to uninstall nodejs as well, but it throws this:
jmlopez@desarrollo:/usr/share$ sudo apt remove nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnode-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
 node-abab : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-aproba : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-archy : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-argparse : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-cacache : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-chalk : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-clone : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-colors : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-combined-stream : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-console-control-strings : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-coveralls : Depends: nodejs:any
 node-cssom : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-debug : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-esprima : Depends: nodejs:any
 node-events : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-graceful-fs : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-gyp : Depends: nodejs:any
 node-js-yaml : Depends: nodejs:any
 node-json-buffer : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-lcov-parse : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-log-driver : Depends: nodejs (>= 10) but it is not going to be installed
 node-mime : Depends: nodejs:any
 node-mkdirp : Depends: nodejs:any
 node-ms : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-nopt : Depends: nodejs:any
 node-normalize-package-data : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-object-assign : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-opener : Depends: nodejs:any
 node-psl : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-punycode : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-read-package-json : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-rimraf : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-semver : Depends: nodejs (>= 10) but it is not going to be installed
 node-source-map-support : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-ssri : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-stack-utils : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-strip-ansi : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-tap : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-tap-mocha-reporter : Depends: nodejs:any
 node-tap-parser : Depends: nodejs:any
 node-unique-filename : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-which : Depends: nodejs:any
 node-write-file-atomic : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-ws : Depends: nodejs:any
 npm : Depends: nodejs:any (>= 10)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

The installed version of nodejs is:
jmlopez@desarrollo:/usr/share$ nodejs -v
v12.22.9

Could these problems be related? Any ideas to fix them?
Thank you very much in advance!!

Did you try: apt --fix-broken install? This is mentioned after you run sudo apt install npm

Yes, I tried, but it rhrows a Failed to fetch error. It might be in relation with a problem in the repositories provided by my cloud server provider

To install Node Package Manager on Ubuntu please try following instruction.

To check update service

sudo apt update



To install Node.js on Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04, use the following command:

sudo apt install nodejs



Verify the Installation

node --version


If Node version display mean you have installed successful
To verify the npm version, execute the following command:
npm --version


Alternative here:
# installs NVM (Node Version Manager)
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash

# download and install Node.js
nvm install 20

# verifies the right Node.js version is in the environment
node -v # should print `v20.12.2`

# verifies the right NPM version is in the environment
npm -v # should print `10.5.0`


read more: HERE

Despite it worked to me, installation seems to be non persistent. I check npm -v and its installed version is correct and it works, but...When I log out and in, npm "dissapears" and even the command npm -v throwa an error (Cannot find semver in node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933

NPM will only "re-appear" if I enter "nvm install 20"

May your Node Version Manager missed configure please check the step below:


Open configure file with command
nano ~/.bashrc


Add the following code to end of the file
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"


Save file


Restart your terminal  or run source ~/.bashrc


Now you can check the npm --version again.

Thanks! I finally got rid of the problem (in fact I had additional errors trying to reinstall nvm) following the directions in this page: [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152570/npm-cant-find-module-semver-error-in-ubuntu-19-04) italic bold code

But... the problem I have now is that I can only access and run npm using sudo, even npm -v
